# Finding Bitwise & operations inside a C Source Code

Tags: java, regex

Good Day RegEx Gurus,

I just would like to request for some help regarding REGEX.

How to find the Bitwise & operator inside a C source code?

Currently I already have this RegEx:

```
[^\&=](\&)[^\&]
```

Case #1 : should Return : 3 (Currently returns 3, which is OK)

```
                 :
u1_dfsmd_igbt_sdown = ( u1r_dfsmd_igbt[IGBT_WSDOWN] &
u1r_dfsmd_igbt[IGBT_SSDOWN] &
u1r_dfsmd_rcv_wsdown &
u1r_dfsmd_rcv_ssdown ) ;
                 :
```

Case #2 : should Return : 0 (Currently returns 1, which is NOT OK)

```
                 :
scanf ("%d", &i)
                 :
```

Case #3 : : should Return : 0 (Currently returns 0, which is OK)

```
                 :
if (xx && yy && zz) {
//Some statements here
}
                 :
```

I'm a beginner w/ RegEx (My current Regex might be in brute-force)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Not a job for regex. Get/write a parser.

Comment: _You_ need to do the work here and define the precise criteria for a `&` to be matched, and _then_ someone may be able to help with a regex. If you don't want a match if `i` follows an `&`, then simply add it to the negated character class.

Comment: I'll try to add the "," to the negate character class. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you need to analyze source code text and you aren't a compiler writer you are already in way over your head. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: I'm Just trying to count the pattern usage (that why I used RegEx).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be enough?

```
\s\&=?\s
```

It's a '&' prefixed by any whitespace character [ \t\n\x0B\f\r] with optional '=' and suffixed with any whitespace character (including new line). I didn't test that and don't know all the criteria but I hope it helps.

Comment: Not all people use whitespace, some write `if (n&1)` for example.